# Remove javascript event from mobile menu button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the default collapse behaviour in a responsive, bootstrap theme for wordpress but I am fairly sure my question relates specifically to Bootstrap.

When the screen width is reduced and the mobile menu icon (hamburger) is clicked on it triggers the collapsing menu. I would like to remove this javascript trigger event and create a new custom event.

The HTML for the button in the theme is:

```
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
```

I have tried using the following javascript to remove the default event but with no luck:

```
$('button.navbar-toggle').unbind();
$('button.navbar-toggle').off();
```

I have also tried applying the unbind() and off() methods to the spans within the button, but again with no luck.

I would be very grateful for any help with this.

Comment: You should open Dev Tool in Chrome to check Theme then Inspected Element for checking Event

Comment: Thank you Koellin, that was helpful. I had tried the inspector in Chrome before but stupidly had 'ancestors' enabled. When I disabled that I can find the event I want to disable.

Comment: if you want remove Event set <button data-toggle:empty> or use preventDefault to disable .

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be useful. Also you can use window resize function.

```
 // detect if your screen is smaller
 if ($('body').width() > 960){
 // intercept click event
   $('.item').click(function(){
     //do some stuff
   })
 }else{
   // intercept click event for larger screens
   $('.item').click(function(){
     //do another stuff
   })
 }
```

Comment: Why is this helpful? Please edit to explain why this addresses the users question!

Comment: I'd have mentioned about `preventDefault` if jQuery doesn't already do that.

Comment: i am newbie Pureferrey. i couldnt even use editor. thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

According to my openion, you should not bother about bind and unbind the different functions for mobile device and desktop.

I would suggest to make a single function in which you can check device type (whether it is mobile or desktop) you can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery) for check device type

and according to that, you can trigger different function, as you want.

Hope this solution works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer AdiechaHK. My problem though is that I am trying to trigger the menu to appear in a different way (slide in from the right side of the page as an overlay, not pushing the content to the left. I can do this in firefox by attaching a new event. In Chrome however the event is being triggered twice. I was asuming that would be because of an existing envent which was bound to the element but that could be incorrect.